# Chkconfig conflict during RPM installation

Tags: fedora, rpm

I work with .rpm. I have made rpm for glassfish

my template file is

```
Summary: GlassFish
Name: redsky-glassfish
Version: @VERSION@
Release: @RELEASE@
License: Proprietary
Group: Applications/System
Buildroot: %{_topdir}/%{name}-%{version}-root
BuildArch: x86_64

Requires: jdk
Conflicts: java-1.7.0-openjdk

%description

%preun

%install
rm -fr ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}
mkdir ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}
cp -r ${RPM_BUILD_DIR}/* ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}

%post

%postun
#0 = uninstall, 1 = upgrade
if [ "$1" == "0" ]; then
    rm -fr /opt/glassfish/
fi

%files
/*
```

During installation it throws error

file /etc/init.d from install of glassfish-development-1095.x86_64 conflicts with file from package chkconfig-1.3.49.3-2.el6.x86_64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `%files` section needs to list only your files in it. You don't own `/etc/init.d`, `chkconfig` does.